# Data-binding generic list in recyclerview

Tags: android, list, generics, data-binding, android-recyclerview

I would like to reuse the same fragment (that contains a RecyclerView) to show different lists:

> List<Pizze>, List<Pasta>, List<Wine>.

Let's consider that i have this 3 objects (Pizze,Pasta,Wine)and all those objects have the same fields: name and price.
This RecyclerView in the fragment should show only those two fields: name and price for every list.
In the layout i have to express the variable type:

> variable name="items" type="List<Pizza>

How can i pass a generic list here?

Answer (score 0):

How about an Object array, first item is the name second is the price.

Comment: That could be a solution but it means that i  have to convert all the list to arrays before setting the data-binding variable.
If i don't find anything better i will go that way.

Comment: Every object inherites from Object so you wont have to convert to array, just a recast back

Answer (score 0):

Just use generics.

```
private List<T> mItems;

public void setItems(List<T> items) {
        mItems = items;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```